# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "char" в "string"

Tags: c#

Программа генератора паролей. Есть возможность выбора - дополнить пароль `символами`. Я создал переменую которая записывает в себя данные с `textBox2.Text` и потом в цикле выполняется генерация. Но возникает ошибка `Ошибка CS0029 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "char" в "string".`.

Я пробовал конвертацию в `char` входных данных в переменую, но не помогло. Подскажите как сделать правильно.

Ещё я хочу замиксовать оба результата (что бы они смешивались и пароль на выходе получался более надежным), подскажите как это реализовать.

Код:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string data = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
            char symbols = Convert.ToChar(textBox2.Text);
            int lon = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            string result = "";
            string result_symbols = "";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int lng = data.Length;
            int lng2 = data.Length;



            for (int i = 0; i < lon; i++)
            {
                result_symbols = Convert.ToChar(symbols[rnd.Next(lng)]);
                result += data[rnd.Next(lng)];
            }

            textBox1.Text = result;
        }
    }
```

Скриншот программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Массив `char[]` от одного символа `char` надо отличать. Строку в массив преобразовать можно так: `char[] symbols = textBox2.Text.ToCharArray();`

Comment: Спасибо, понял теперь. Не подскажие если не сложно, как можно выходные результаты - `замиксовать`, обьединить две строки. Может что-то связаное с `StringBuilder` использовать, или как?

Comment: `char[] newArray = array1.Concat(array2).ToArray()`

Comment: Извините, я немного туплю, куда вставить эту строчку? @aepot

Comment: а не проще ли склеить 2 строки? `(строка1 + строка2).ToCharArray()`? Так легче?

Comment: Понял, правда возникает ошибка `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."`, при генерации с использованием символов.

Comment: Где-то опечатались, внимательно проверяйте свой код, где-то не тот Length использовали в цикле.

Comment: Ну если так смотреть, у меня вроде везде  `Lenght` указан. Может тут стоит через цикл сделать?
`result_symbols = Convert.ToString(symbols[rnd.Next(lng)]);`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132529/discussion-between-zekoy-and-aepot).

Comment: `symbols[rnd.Next(lng)]` lng чему равно? длине массива data, так? но ведь он длиннее, чем массив symbols? почему вы используете длину одного массива как границу индексов другого? Будьте внимательны.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TEf8IRj.png - но у меня вроде все верно указано.

Comment: `result_symbols = Convert.ToString(symbols[rnd.Next(lng)]);` даже при правильной lng это работать не будет как вам надо - `result_symbols = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, lon).Select(_ => symbols[rnd.Next(lng)]));` ну или в цикле `result_symbols += symbols[rnd.Next(lng)];` и не мудрите с этими Convert, они вас только больше запутают.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/D9YYjVE.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть у вас будет список строк, каждая из которых представляет определенный диапазон. Создайте консольное приложение, чтобы проверить, как работает код, который я покажу, и только потом переносите его в свой проект.

Но для начала, создадим метод, который генерирует строчку, от нужного символа нужной длины. Всегда разбивайте свои задачи на методы, так будет проще работать с кодом.

```cs
private string GetRangeString(char first, int length)
{
    return string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(first, length).Select(c => (char)c));
}
```

Чтобы понять, как можно таким образом составлять диапазоны символов - посмотрите в таблицу символов ASCII, и сразу станет понятно, что английские буквы и цифры идут по порядку. С русскими сложнее, там не все по порядку, но они вам вроде и не нужны. Для русских в C# используется кодировка UTF-16 (Unicode).

Далее, можно начать составлять словарь из нужных наборов символов.

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(GetRangeString('A', 26)); // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
list.Add(GetRangeString('a', 26)); // abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
list.Add(GetRangeString('0', 10)); // 0123456789
list.Add("=/.;!?");                // =/.;!?
```

Как видите в список можно просто добавлять строки с любым содержимым. Список предлагаю для того, чтобы вы галочками и настройками в интерфейсе могли регулировать наполнение словаря просто добавив несколько `if` в код.

Теперь надо составить из этого строку из уникальных символов.

```cs
string dictionary = string.Concat(string.Concat(list).Distinct());
Console.WriteLine(dictionary);
```

*(для опытных: да, здесь хорошо подойдет так же Linq `SelectMany`)*

Готово, вывод в консоль

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789=/.;!?
```

`Distinct()` как раз и удаляет из строки повторяющиеся символы.

Теперь сделать используя этот словарь пароль нужной длины

```cs
int length = 8;
Random rnd = new Random();

string password = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, length).Select(_ => dictionary[rnd.Next(dictionary.Length)]));

Console.WriteLine(password);
```

Вот и все решение. Я конечно обильно использовал Linq, но это же самое можно сделать на простых циклах, типа как у вас. Смысл этого ответа как раз в том, чтобы показать, как самому составить словарь символов из нескольких наборов.

Кстати, чтобы пробежаться по строке циклом, не нужно преобразовывать ее в массив символов, потому что строка это и есть массив символов, и можно к этим символам так же обращаться по индексу, как в обычном символьном массиве. Единственно отличие - вы не сможете перезаписывать символы в строке, а только читать.

Вывод в консоль

```
LS4gAZ.J
```

---

Весь код, чтобы поиграться

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(GetRangeString('A', 26));
    list.Add(GetRangeString('a', 26));
    list.Add(GetRangeString('0', 10));
    list.Add("=/.;!?");

    string dictionary = string.Concat(string.Concat(list).Distinct());
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary);

    int length = 8;
    string password = GeneratePassword(dictionary, length);
    Console.WriteLine(password);
}

private static string GeneratePassword(string dictionary, int length)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, length).Select(_ => dictionary[rnd.Next(dictionary.Length)]));
}

private static string GetRangeString(char first, int length)
{
    return string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(first, length).Select(c => (char)c));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробное обьяснение =), внесло ясность, и извините что тупил, C# мне дается трудом. Ещё раз большое спасибо.

Comment: @Zekoy домашка :) чтобы понять, что я вам тут понаписал до конца, перепишите всякие Linq запросы на простые понятные циклы. Это будет непросто, но это даст вам во-первых, понимание, что здесь вообще происходит. Во-вторых познакомитесь с Linq и сможете самостоятельно его использовать в будущем.

Comment: Конечно немного широкий вопрос, но все же - я вижу вы хороший специалист в области языка, не могли бы подсказать, `направить` к тому где и как учить? Может книги какие-нибудь или сайты-самоучки, я пару конечно из них знаю, но все же уже 2-ой год подряд - ничего так и существеного не добился, мне нравится программирование - у меня есть желание делать свое, но либо я просто тупой для этого или сам не знаю, искренее уже выгораю постоянно и ищу решения на stackoveflow что бы не думать, что можете посоветовать если вам не сложно и не затруднит.

Comment: @Zekoy я начинал с [этих видео](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ).

Comment: Спасибо, завтра начну смотреть =).

Answer (score 1):

Вот простая реализация.
Инициализировать константы только один раз как константы или переменные класса.
Отделяйте служебные функции от UI кода.

```
    private const string Letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    private const string Symbols = "~...";
    private readonly char[] _lettersAndSymbols = (Letters + Symbols).ToCharArray();
    private readonly int _lettersAndSymbolsLength = (Letters + Symbols).Length;
    private readonly Random _rnd = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox2.Text = Symbols ;
    }

    private string GeneratePassword(int length)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            result += _lettersAndSymbols[_rnd.Next(_lettersAndSymbolsLength)];
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lon = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        textBox1.Text = GeneratePassword(lon);
    }
```

Comment: А что за `textBox2.Text = _symbolString;` ?

Comment: @Zekoy Исправленная ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Вот более правильный код, напишите, если будут проблемы

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string standard = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<char> symbols = textBox2.Text.ToList();
            string result = "";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
                result += symbols[rnd.Next(0, symbols.Count)].ToString();
            textBox1.Text = result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Не удается применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "char`, та же ошибка что и у меня.

Comment: Cейчас всё сделаю, жди

Comment: Благодарю, немного поковырялся и понял, я его ещё немного доработал потому что тут не использовались в генерации символы, спасибо за помощь. =)